# how to solve this inaccessible due to his protection level error?

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

i am creating a one withdarw window my database connection code is right and its display result on same form correctly i want to show the result on next form .
i am implemeted code for that .give me error  " inaccessible due to protection level "  i search many code but not got any solutions .

this give on this line error " rece.Default.lblbal.Text = balance;".

this my code :

```
      namespace ATMManagementSystem
      {
      public partial class cust_cash_with_sav : Form
      {

      public cust_cash_with_sav()
      {
        InitializeComponent();
      }
      #region Default Instance

      public static cust_cash_with_sav defaultInstance;

      /// <summary>
      /// Added by the VB.Net to C# Converter to support default instance  behavour in C#
    /// </summary>
    public static cust_cash_with_sav Default
    {
        get
        {
            if (defaultInstance == null)
            {
                defaultInstance = new cust_cash_with_sav();
                defaultInstance.FormClosed += new 
                FormClosedEventHandler(defaultInstance_FormClosed);
            }

            return defaultInstance;
        }
    }

    static void defaultInstance_FormClosed(object sender, 
    FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        defaultInstance = null;
    }
    #endregion

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=VAIO;Initial 
    Catalog=ATM;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataSet ds;
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int total1;
    string balance;
    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sql = default(string);
        DataTable Log_in = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM user_transaction 
            where  pin_number = " + textBox2.Text + "", con);
            cmd.Connection = con;

            //da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);


            da.Fill(Log_in);
            if (Log_in.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                balance = (string)(Log_in.Rows[0]["Total"].ToString());
                num1 = int.Parse(balance);
                num2 = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);

                if (num2 > 25000)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You can Only Withdraw Php 25,000");
                }
                else if (num2 < 200)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(" Mininum withdrawal is 200");
                }
                else if (num1 < num2)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(" Insuffiecient balance");

                }
                else
                {
                    total1 = num1 - num2;

                    rece.Default.Show();
                    rece.Default.lblbal.Text = balance;
                    rece.Default.lbldep.Hide();
                    rece.Default.lblwith.Text = num2.ToString();
                    rece.Default.lblnewbal.Text = total1.ToString();
                    rece.Default.lblbal.Show();
                    rece.Default.lbldep.Hide();
                    rece.Default.lblwith.Show();
                    rece.Default.lblnewbal.Show();
                    //MsgBox("success")
                    rece.Default.lblname.Text = 
                    Mainmenu.Default.lblname.Text;
                    label2.Text = total1.ToString();
                    //this.Hide();


                }
            }
            else
            {


            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // MessageBox.Show(" Pls. Enter Ammount!");
            //MsgBox(ex.Message)
        }
        textBox1.Text = "";


      }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
//In Form1's 
using(rece form2 = new rece()) 
{

   form2.TheValue = someControlOnForm1.Text;

}
```

And...

```
 //In rece form
    //Create a public property to serve the value
    public string TheValue 
    {
      set { lblbal.Text = value;}
    }
```